# Users can only view their own notes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have an application where i'm using devise for authentication,
I have a USER model, those users can create publications, some publications that can be seen by all the users I called Articles and I represent them in the ARTICLE model, the same users can also create Notes, I have represented them in the NOTE model, but Unlike publications, these Notes can only be viewed or accessed by the users who created them and not by other users, for example:
myapp / articles / 5 (all users can access)
myapp / notes / 5 (can only be accessed by the user who created them)
The controller for the index view I have it like this:

```
    def index
    @notes = current_user.notes
  end

  def show
    @note = Note.find params[:id]
  end
```

The problem is that I can't get only creator users to access the notes in the show view, since by changing the ID number in the browser, another user accesses the note that does not correspond to him.
In the Index view I had no problem because I can get the list of the notes that were created by its users.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You could do a `before_action` to check if the note does not belong to the user who tried to access it.

Something like:

```rb
class NotesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_note, only: :show
  before_action :verify_permission, only: :show

  # Your code here...

  private
  def set_note
    @note = Note.find(params[:id])
  end

  def verify_permission
    redirect_to notes_path if !user_signed_in? || @note.user != current_user
  end
end
```

Explaining the code:

- `set_note` makes your code cleaner. If you're going to use the same `@note = Note.find(params[:id])` in other actions (edit, update or destroy) you could simply add them to the `before_action` callback and avoid using the same code 4 times.
- `verify_permission` checks if the user is logged in and if the note belongs to the user who created it. If one of these conditions is not matched, the user is redirected to the notes path (it could be whatever you want). If you would also like to run this verification on edit or destroy, just add the keys on the `before_action` as well.

An example if you want to verify the permission on more than 1 action:

`before_action :verify_permission, only: %i[show edit update destroy]`

Comment: Thank you so much Andrea. it worked for me like this: def verify_permission
    redirect_to notes_path if !user_signed_in? || @note.user != current_user
  end

Comment: Oh, the `!==` should be a `!=`. My mistake! I fixed that in my answer. But I'm glad it worked for you :)